# Select Fiscal day,week,month in Biqquery

Tags: google-bigquery

My Financial year starts from September.
I need to select Fiscal day number, Fiscal week number, Fiscal Month number, Fiscal Quarter number, Fiscal Quarter Name

I am getting date range from below query :

```sql
select date_sub(boms, interval 0 day) as start_date
from unnest(generate_date_array('2020-01-01','2050-12-31', interval 1 day)) boms
```

```
Example : 
2020-01-01
2020-01-02
2020-01-03
.....
.....
2025-12-31
```

The output i need to get :
For Example for the date : 11-Feb-2020

```
Output:
FISCAL_DAY_OF_YEAR_NUMBER- 162
FISCAL_WEEK_OF_YEAR_NUMBER- 24
FISCAL_MONTH_NUMBER - 6
FISCAL_QUARTER_NUMBER - 2
FISCAL_QUARTER_NAME - Third
```

Comment: Any help here ?

Comment: How are you counting the week of the year? For example if 09-01 falls on a Friday or Thursday, are you counting that as week 1? Just want to confirm since BQ counts these types of scenarios as week 0 and it might cause a mismatch of 1 week to your expected data.

Comment: The week counting should start from week 1 for Jan-01

Comment: 1st week of the fiscal year is at Jan-01?

Comment: No, the First wee will start start based on Fiscal year Sep-01. I am trying to say the week number should start with 1 instead of 0

Comment: Do you already have a query for this, yet you are having a 0 instead of 1?